# Bitmap Image from Hex string - extra bytes being added

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap, postscript

I have a Hex string that's coming from postscript file.

```
<< /ImageType 1
/Width 986 /Height 1
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1]
/ImageMatrix [986 0 0 -1 0 1]
/DataSource <
803fe0503824160d0784426150b864361d0f8844625138a4562d178c466351b8e4763d1f904864523924964d27944a6552b964b65d2f984c665339a4d66d379c4e6753b9e4f67d3fa05068543a25168d47a4526954ba648202
> /LZWDecode filter >> image } def
```

Below are the methods that I am using. I have commented out the method for updating color.

```
public static void ProcessImageColourMapping()
{
    string imageDataSource = "803fe0503824160d0784426150b864361d0f8844625138a4562d178c466351b8e4763d1f904864523924964d27944a6552b964b65d2f984c665339a4d66d379c4e6753b9e4f67d3fa05068543a25168d47a4526954ba648202";
    string imageDataSourceUpdated = GetUpdatedImage(imageDataSource);
}

public static string GetUpdatedImage(string strImageDataSource)
{
    string imageDataSourceUpdated = "";

    byte[] imageBytes = StringToByteArray(strImageDataSource);
    Bitmap bitmapImage = ByteArrayToBitmap(imageBytes);
    //UpdateColour(bitmapImage);
    byte[] imageBytesUpdated = BitmapToByteArray(bitmapImage);
    imageDataSourceUpdated = ByteArrayToString(imageBytesUpdated);

    return imageDataSourceUpdated;
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String imageHexString)
{
    int numberOfChars = imageHexString.Length / 2;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[numberOfChars];
    using (var sr = new StringReader(imageHexString))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars; i++)
            byteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
    }
    return byteArray;
}

public static Bitmap ByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
    int width = 986; //width and height are taken from postscript file for testing a single hex string.
    int height = 1; 
    Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    BitmapData bmpData = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);            
    try
    {                
        Marshal.Copy(byteArray, 0, bmpData.Scan0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);                
    }
    return bitmapImage;
}

public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapData bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;
    byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(bmpdata.Scan0, bytedata, 0, numbytes);            
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
    }
    return bytedata;
}

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(byteArray.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in byteArray)
    {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }
    return hex.ToString();
}
```

**Issue:**
In below code, I am not updating anything for incoming Hex string `imageDataSource`.
Converting it to byte[] - then to Bitmap - Back to byte[] - and finally back to Hex string.

So, `imageDataSourceUpdated` should have same value as `imageDataSource`.
However, when I finally check the value for `imageDataSourceUpdated`, it comes out as:

`803fe0503824160d0784426150b864361d0f8844625138a4562d178c466351b8e4763d1f904864523924964d27944a6552b964b65d2f984c665339a4d66d379c4e6753b9e4f67d3fa05068543a25168d47a4526954ba64820200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.....
So many zeros being appended.

Can please guide what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you try using `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` instead of `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` in your `ByteArrayToBitmap` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing some input string, but the width of the image (and so 1/4 of the size of the byte array) is set to 986 in your sample, which would yield the behaviour you observe - you're not actually passing `986 * 4` bytes of data, but the Bitmap does have that many. So you'll get the first X bytes you actually copied to the bitmap, and then all zeros. In other words, it seems your issue is with your sample data, not with the methods themselves - those work just fine.

Comment: Hi Luaan, I am getting this input HEX string and size from our client's postscript file. Do you know of any way to create bitmap of the 'right size' just by using Hex string? Thank you!

Comment: @iniki You have to read the data before the image itself, something like `40 45 1 [ 40 0 0 -45 0 45 ]`. This tells you the parameters of the bitmap - the first three numbers are width, height and bytes per pixel. The length of the data string then should be `width * height * BPP * 2`, and you should create the bitmap of the correct size and format. In my example, this would be eg. `new Bitmap(40, 45, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);`

Comment: 'read the data before image itself', did you mean /ImageMatrix [986 0 0 -1 0 1] please have a look at my updated question - added whole image def block from ps file

Comment: @iniki In your sample, it's the Width, Height and BitsPerComponent. However, seeing the whole definition now, the problem is even more complicated, since the image data is actually compressed, using LZW. So, you should be expecting 986 bytes of data (986 width, 1 height, 1 byte per pixel). So - get the data string, convert it to byte[] as you have, decompress (eg. http://sharplzw.sourceforge.net/), create the bitmap as `new Bitmap(986, 1, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);`, do your manipulation, get the byte[], compress, encode to data string and you're done.