# Postscript file Image and C# Bitmap

Tags: c#, postscript

I have images defined like below in postscript file:

```
<< /ImageType 1
/Width 986 /Height 1
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1]
/ImageMatrix [986 0 0 -1 0 1]
/DataSource <
803fe0503824160d0784426150b864361d0f8844625138a4562d178c466351b8e4763d1f904864523924964d27944a6552b964b65d2f984c665339a4d66d379c4e6753b9e4f67d3fa05068543a25168d47a4526954ba648202
> /LZWDecode filter >> image } def
```

using the image DataSource, I need to create a C# bitmap object.

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(986, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
```

I don't have much knowledge about ps files.
Depending on info available in ps block, can anyone please confirm following:

- Which PixelFormat to use here - I am currently using PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb?
- Is '/Width 986 /Height 1' is the right image size to use when creating C# Bitmap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which PixelFormat to use here - I am currently using
>   PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb?

Instead of `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` i would use `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed` because of this line: `/BitsPerComponent 8`

Anyway, you can use other format, it will be converted

> Is '/Width 986 /Height 1' is the right image size to use when creating
>   C# Bitmap?

Yes it is: **width**=986 / **height**=1
Only if you want to create a `Bitmap` respecting **width** and **height** in Postscript file

Comment: Hi Justin, Do you want to have a look at my another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529438/bitmap-image-from-hex-string-extra-bytes-being-added  Please see if you have any clue.